# O que são Sockets de rede e WebSockets?

Tags: http, socket, terminologia, websocket, redes

Estou estudando programação de node.js real-time e me surgiram algumas dúvidas a respeito de Sockets de rede. Não achei nada detalhadamente explicado, dai resolvi abrir a questão.

O que é um socket de rede e um WebSocket? Qual a diferença entre os dois? Uma comunicação HTTP baseada em requisição-resposta sem ser em tempo real é dada através de um socket? Qual é o papel do protocolo TCP nos sockets e WebSockets?

Comment: Eu estou exatamente com a mesma dúvida. Eu usei o WebSocket do HTML5, criei um chat, mas ainda assim, não sei exatamente diferenciar as definições (em relação a conceitos e tal)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[**WebSockets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) e [**Sockets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) são ambos protocolos de comunicação entre cliente e servidor,  mas embora possuam certas semelhanças (além do nome), são especificações distintas para finalidades também diferentes.

## Sockets

O protocolo **Socket** é usado para comunicação entre processos através da rede, transmitindo dados em formato binário. Para a comunicação na rede, ele opera sobre algum protocolo de como TCP ou UDP para abstrair as complexidades inerentes do meio de transmissão. Cada Socket conecta-se a uma porta específica. Sockets são soluções genéricas, geralmente usados para comunicação de alto desempenho entre diferentes plataformas.

## WebSockets

O protocolo **WebSocket**, por sua vez, possui a finalidade muito mais específica de ser implementado em navegadores web para comunicação persistente do código JavaScript com o servidor web, comunicando-se geralmente através da porta `80` e sempre sobre o protocolo `TCP`. O formato do protocolo é em texto e o *handshake* que inicia a comunicação é muito parecido com o HTTP, assim servidores web podem facilmente servir HTTP e WebSockets na mesma porta.

Comment: o Socket é persistente?

Comment: @ropbla9 Sockets TCP são devido à próprio natureza do protocolo, que mantém estado da conexão. Sockets UDP não se conectam realmente a nenhum outro host, apenas enviam *streams* de dados pela rede, então poderíamos dizer que não são persistentes (nem faria sentido ser).

Comment: então a conexão entre dois sites não é persistente devido à natureza do HTTP, e que se dependesse do TCP, seria?

Comment: @ropbla A conexão entre o navegador e o servidor é persistente  em baixo nível no sentido de que ela persiste até o fim da requisição. Porém o protocolo Http em mais alto nível não é persistente porque após fazer a requisição e obter uma resposta, ele irá encerrar a conexão TCP.

Comment: @utluiz Você já fez integração com websocket?

Answer (score 15):

[**Sockets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) são as extremidades de uma comunicação entre dois processos (aplicativos) através de uma rede de computadores. No sistema operacional essas extremidades são recursos que o sistema cria por solicitação dos processos para que estes possam se comunicar pela rede. Como hoje em dia a maioria da comunicação entre computadores é baseada no [Protocolo de Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), a maioria dos *sockets* são *sockets de Internet*. Do ponto de vista do programador eles são acessados através de uma API (do sistema operacional ou indiretamente através de uma biblioteca) que torna possível estabelecer comunicação com um "endereço de socket" (uma combinação única de um endereço IP e um número de porta).

Dois tipos de socket são mais comuns, os *stream sockets* (que por debaixo dos panos usam o protocolo TCP na camada de transporte, por isso costumo chamá-los de sockets TCP) e os *datagram sockets* (que usam o protocolo UDP). A diferença entre eles é que os sockets TCP mantêm a conexão com o outro lado aberta ao longo de toda a comunicação e garantem a chegada dos dados (bytes) na sequência em que foram enviados. Já os sockets UDP não estabelecem conexão, apenas "jogam" um pacote de dados na rede e não garantem que esses dados cheguem ao outro lado nem que sua ordem seja respeitada.

Com sockets você pode implementar comunicação entre processos ou até mesmo um protocolo de mais alto nível (chamado de protocolo de aplicação, devido à camada que ele se localiza no [modelo ISO/OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) que outros desenvolvedores poderão usar, como o próprio HTTP ou o [**WebSocket**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), que são protocolos de aplicação implementados sobre sockets TCP.

Como o HTTP segue uma sequência bem definida de passos (abrir a conexão, fazer a requisição, receber a resposta e fechar a conexão), em geral ele dá a impressão de não ser persistente. Mas por baixo dos panos ele está executando esses passos sobre uma comunicação persistente, permitida pelo TCP. Existem técnicas que mantêm a conexão HTTP aberta por um longo tempo para transmissão persistente de dados (vide [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))). São "gambiarras".

Porém, uma forma mais apropriada de se manter uma conexão aberta entre navegadores pelo JavaScript para troca de dados em tempo real é o comparativamente novo protocolo WebSocket. Ele é um protocolo de aplicação, também baseado em TCP, que pode ser implementado por servidores web e servido na mesma porta do HTTP (porta 80). O HTTP foi relativamente bem pensado e permite essa "migração" de um protocolo de aplicação para outro, após ter sido feito um *handshake* inicial em HTTP.

Pode-se concluir então que, apesar da similaridade dos nomes, são conceitos diferentes. WebSocket é um protocolo de comunicação entre aplicativos (navegadores), que por debaixo dos panos tem seus dados transportados pelo protocolo TCP, que por sua vez faz a ponte entre dois *sockets* (conceito do sistema operacional). Em outras palavras, o WebSocket usa sockets.