# O que são Sockets? E como desenvolver em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, socket, terminologia

Tenho que desenvolver um Socket, mas não sei o que é nem como funciona! Queria saber o que é necessário para criar um Socket em C#, estou usando como IDE o Visual Studio.

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta responde metade da sua [O que são Sockets de rede e WebSockets?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46839/28595)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Socket (tomada) é o ponto final da comunicação de dados de um processo com outro na mesma máquina ou em outra. É um mecanismo normalmente fornecido pelos sistemas operacionais para estabelecer comunicação de dados.

Isto pode ser obtido com a classe [`Socket`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) no .NET (em exemplo na página da documentação).

Exemplo básico:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
...
var Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Sockets.cs).

Existem algumas [formas de comunicação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.addressfamily?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), [tipos de "tomadas"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) diferentes (Stream, Dgram, Raw, Rdm, Seqpacket) e [protocolos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.protocoltype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) disponíveis (TCP, UDP, ICMP, IPv4, IPv6, entre outros).

Só deve usá-lo para construir mecanismos de comunicação de baixo nível. Tem que ter um bom entendimento de comunicação de dados. Em geral quem usa isto, é quem fará mecanismo personalizado de FTP, HTTP, SMTP, etc., ou quem precisa do uso da comunicação direta em nível mais baixo e está disposto a lidar com todos detalhes necessários. Se não tiver um bom motivo para usá-lo, prefira outro mecanismo.

[Exemplos práticos](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using).