# Como conectar Socket com Websocket?

Tags: html, aplicação-web, visual-basic-6

Talvez o título esteja meio bobo, mas vou explicar, Tenho um Servidor Socket que fiz em VB e também tenho um Client Socket feito em Javascript pra web, único problema é que para o Client(Web) entenda que a conexão estabelecida é necessário que o servidor retorne 101, do contrario:

[image: Pending...]

ele fica em "Pending" até que desconectar-se, ainda não sei como fazer com que o servidor retorne isso, Alguém poderia explicar como fazer?

Já foi um pouco chato desenvolver o servidor em Visual Basic porque os exemplos que achei na internet eram muito simples, meu código também rsrs

```html
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net

Module Principal
    Dim ServerIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.3")
    Dim Server As New TcpListener(ServerIP, 80)
    Dim Client As New TcpClient
    Dim Reader As StreamReader
    Dim Writer As StreamWriter

    Sub Main()
        Server.Start()
        Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient
        Dim Thread As New Thread(AddressOf Receive)
        Thread.Start()
        While Client.Connected
            Dim m = Console.ReadLine
            If Len(m) Then
                Writer = New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream)
                Writer.WriteLine(m)
                Writer.Flush()
            End If
        End While
    End Sub
    Sub Receive()
        While Client.Connected
            Reader = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)
            Dim Received = Reader.ReadLine
            If Len(Received) Then
                Console.WriteLine(Received)
            End If
        End While
        Main()
    End Sub


End Module
```

Bem, se alguém poder ajudar eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Você tem consciência de que tem todo um protocolo que você precisa escrever para fazer o VB servir Websockets, né? Mais detalhes aqui: [O que são Sockets de rede e WebSockets?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46839/70)

Comment: pelo que vi tem o "101 Switching Protocols", ainda to com dificuldades pra implementar mas obrigado cara, valeu.

Comment: Esse é só o começo. Tem que fazer o handshake todo, fornecer os cabeçalhos, e ao trocar dados, tem um formato padronizado. Websockets tem um nome muito mal escolhido (quase sempre os padrões da web são mal feitos), não tem nada a ver com os sockets normais.