# Diferença entre requisição/resposta normal, long-polling, websockets, WebRTC e Server-Sent Events?

Tags: http, independente-de-linguagem

Eu tinha uma ideia errada do *long-polling*, comecei a notar que na verdade ele é uma "técnica" que roda em cima de uma requisição normal, nisto comecei a pesquisar e notei várias perguntas no site, mas a maioria é "como fazer", gostaria de entender a diferença entre *WebSockets*, *WebRTC*, *Server-Sent Events*, *requisições HTTP normais* e *long-polling*.

Eu já tenho conhecimento sobre websocket e HTTP, todavia abri esta questão porque vejo que existem mais tecnologias e acho que seria interessante saber aonde se diferenciam.

Gostaria também de um detalhamento sobre long-polling, ele realmente ajuda? Porque esta "espera" que ele faz eu não consigo enxergar vantagem alguma, me parece que se houver múltiplas requisições vai ser pior que uma requisição HTTP normal.

```
while (true) {
    if (condição para liberar os dados) {
         Resposta
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Requisição/Resposta "normal"

Isto é o protocolo `HTTP` em si. É iniciativa do cliente fazer uma requisição para o servidor. O servidor dará uma resposta. O servidor não pode tomar iniciativa de enviar informação para o cliente sem que ele lhe faca um pedido na versão `HTTP 1.1` (acho que mudou na 2).

**Esta é uma explicação adicional porque funciona dessa forma**

O protocolo HTTP é um protocolo de nível aplicacional que utiliza o protocolo `TCP` como protocolo de comunicação. Os protocolos de comunicação normalmente [utilizam sockets](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46839) para transmitir dados.

Portanto o cliente e o servidor tem que abrir um socket para enviar pedidos e receber respostas (respectivamente). Os sockets são bidireccionais, ou seja, eles permitem comunicar em ambas as direcções (receber e enviar).

Contudo é possível fechar uma das direcções se ela não for usada (como é caso do HTTP). É por este motivo que o cliente apenas consegue enviar pedidos para o servidor.

[Diferença principal entre sockets bidirecionais e unidirecionais no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21057882)

## Long-polling e polling

**Long-polling**

O long-polling é um comportamento especifico a nível aplicacional. Na utilização de long-polling o cliente fica á espera do servidor lhe envie um conjunto de dados.

Imagine que você tem um servidor com aplicação web de tarefas.
Imagine agora que o servidor ainda não tem quaisquer dados e um cliente pede para obter uma lista de Todos. Contudo o cliente prefere que na maior parte das vezes essa lista não esteja vazia.

Então o servidor fica á espera que outros clientes (ou até o mesmo cliente) criem tarefas. E apenas quando existir pelo menos 1 tarefa ele envia uma resposta para o cliente.

Contudo o servidor apenas pode "aguentar" a resposta por determinado período de tempo porque é normal os pedidos terem um timeout máximo (normalmente este timeout é configurável no cliente). Isto quer dizer que o long-polling não pode dar garantias que haverá um conjunto de dados a enviar (neste caso tarefas).

**Polling**

Já o polling funciona um pouco diferente. O cliente vai enviando pedidos para o servidor de x em x tempo á espera que o servidor lhe de informações novas. O servidor não bloqueia á espera que um cliente crie tarefas.

---

Como você mencionou quer o long-polling quer o polling são técnicas primitivas e que na verdade não dão quaisquer tipo de garantias. (Repare que nem o polling nem o long-polling asseguram que haverá dados novos).

## Web-sockets

Web-sockets é um protocolo diferente do HTTP. Ao contrário do HTTP ele permite comunicação bidireccional no cliente e no servidor.

Seguindo o mesmo exemplo da aplicação de tarefas isto quer dizer que o servidor pode enviar um pedido para o cliente quando ele tiver tarefas novas. Nesta abordagem não existe qualquer tipo de bloqueamento por parte do servidor nem o servidor recebe pedidos desnecessários por parte dos clientes (que esperam obter dados novos).

Veja também um exemplo de um cliente javascript web-scoket. (funcionando!!)

```js
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://protocols.herokuapp.com/web-sockets");

ws.onopen = function()
{
    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
    ws.send("Message to send");
    console.log('Client sent message');
};

ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
{ 
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    console.log("Server sent: " + received_msg)
};

ws.onclose = function()
{ 
    // websocket is closed.
    console.log("Connection is closed..."); 
};
```

## Server-Sent events

Este protocolo é uma aplicação do protocolo HTTP. Mas desta vez é o servidor quem envia pedidos (ele acaba com a limitação do cliente não poder receber pedidos). O processamento de pedidos é normalmente feito registando handlers para eventos.

[Veja uma explicação mais detalhada de Server-Sent events no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195452)

```js
  var source = new EventSource('https://protocols.herokuapp.com/sse-hello');

  source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
  }, false);
```

[**Veja o código do servidor!**](https://bitbucket.org/findplate/protocols-node/src)

## WebRTC

O WebRTC parece ser um protocolo especializado para transmissão de media (video e audio). Este protocolo segue um modelo `p2p` onde os clientes transmitem dados entre eles. Isto quer dizer que o número de pedidos feito ao servidor que contém o recurso é mínima.

[Veja uma explicação mais detalhada do WebRTC no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18799364)